# Views slideshow not displaying images

Tags: 8, views

I created a content type with title, body, and slide (image) fields. I created a view block (format: bootstrap carousel, fields: slide).

After I place the block in a region, I see the slideshow block, but I don't see the image. I only see blank slideshow on my site and views.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I display images in the slideshow?

Views > settings next to format > selected image field to display.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is probably a problem in your field display settings.

Comment: I am not sure what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Go to admin > structure > content types > your content type > display settings or something like that. And then see if something looks wrong with your slide field

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in display settings. I do not see any errors. I added the slide field to content type > selected Image > save.  In views, if I add Title field. I can see title in slideshow. I am not sure why it would not display Slide field.

Comment: Try to view the node from node/id and see if the image shows there

Comment: Yes, I can see the image in node/id.

Answer (score 0):

**Views** > Select **Settings** next to format > selected Slide(image) in Image drop down list. I am not sure this is a best solution. At least I can see the image now.

[image] field to display.